# audacity and audio studio softwares on ubuntu mate (raspberry pi 4 b)

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate

how can i install ubuntu studio tools on rpi 4b ubuntu mate os?
I guess it should work with APT package manager. Will that work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this will work. Audacity [is available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=audacity) for both *armhf* and *arm64*. Installation is as simple as

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

Ubuntu Studio packages are also [available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=ubuntustudio) for both *armhf* and *arm64*, to install audio tools use:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-audio
```